# C: fopen() always reurns NULL

Tags: c, fopen

I don't know what happend but everytime i opening file with fopen it returns NULL
but if I try to print address it's print valid address
If i try to read write to other file nothing happend, I opening it in "w" mode, and I opened all the permissions for all users.

[image]

Comment: Where do you see that `fopen` returned null??? Nothing in what you posted suggests that `fp` or `dest` is null. Where did you get that idea? While it is incorrect to use `%d` specifier to `printf` pointers (why did you use it?), your output clearly shows that pointers are *not null*.

Answer (score 2):

Use \\ instead of // in your pathnames. The slash ( / ) symbol doesn't need to be written twice when inside a C string. On the other way, the backslash symbol ( \ ) must be written twice if used inside a C string to not to be confused with an escape character.

I'm not sure, but I think Windows also accepts / as directory separator for filenames.

Comment: errno returns "no error". fopen() doesn't return NULL, so... what isn't working?

Comment: BTW: that's not the best method to copy a binary file to another one. What if the EOF character code is present anywhere in the source file? Better use `fread()` and `fwrite()`

Comment: `EOF` is not a character, but you're right in that `c` needs to be an `int`, not a `char`.

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing up the syntax - either of these should work:

```
fp = fopen("D:\\shortcut\\asd.jpg", "r");
```

or

```
fp = fopen("D:/shortcut/asd.jpg", "r");
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a few errors.

- fetc() returns an int, not a char, assigning the fgetc() return value to a char will make it impossible to distinguish EOF from an actual byte in the file.
- You're opening binary files, so you need to tell fopen() that fact, the default is to open files in text mode.
- `//` is not the directory separator on windows, `\` or `/` is. Since `\` needs escaping when in a C string literal, it would need to be `\\`
- You should check if fopen succeed, and issue a relevant error if it fails.
- You should post code, not screenshot of code.

Do:

```
FILE *fp, *dest;
int c;

if ((fp = fopen("D:\\shortcut\\asd.jpg", "rb")) == NULL) {
    perror("fp fopen");
    return 1;
}
if ((dest = fopen("D:\\sssssssssssss.jpg", "wb")) == NULL) {
    perror("dest fopen");
    return 1;
}

while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
  putc(c, dest); //might even want to check if putc fails.
}

fclose(dest);
fclose(fp);

return 0;
```